# Is it possible to create a script out of my dbml file?

Tags: sql, linq, datacontext

I have a table like T1 with columns C1 and C2. I have the dbml with this table T1.

I want to generate the script for Insert/Update/delete.

For eg: 
I don't want datacontext to excute the task.

```
db.T1.InsertOnSubmit(T);  
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Instead I want the script alone.

```
INSERT INTO 
[DB].[dbo].[T1]("C1","C2")
Values
("abc","abc")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things you could try:

1. You could set up a test class that calls all of the methods from which you'd like to have the SQL, and then use SQL Server Profiler to capture the SQL executed
2. Similar to above, but instead of using the Profiler, you could set `db.Log = Console.Out` to view the generated SQL in a console application
3. Use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to generate your DB context; it allows you to see the generated SQL by switching from the "Results" tab to the "SQL" tab